# Why is it recommended to make API calls in a Chrome Extension's background page rather than a content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a content script which makes an API call to the backend of my website.

I have read in the docs and in many stack overflow answers that it is a bad practice to make API calls directly from the content script, and that it is best to send a message to the background for it to make the request instead (and then return the result). But why ?

Comment: Modern Chrome blocks cross-origin requests in content scripts to [improve security](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches). It's been postponed a few times but soon it'll be fully enforced in Chrome 83.

Comment: I see, thank you for your reply.

Comment: On the same note, it says here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr that for a background script to perform cross-origin requests, host permissions must be declared in the manifest.json. However, I am able to so without these permissions (my website backend allows any origin). Will this change too or am I missing something ?

Comment: You can emulate the future behavior, see "Recommended Developer Actions" section.